# PHP require - visibility scope

Tags: php, scope, visibility, require

I found similar questions, but they didn't really target my problem.

I have a problem with my configuration file. I have index.php which requires config.php (it contains array of settings), later, index.php requires init.php (contains lots of require clause, the most important atm is router.php it requires). Router.php uses settings from config.php, but apparently it's not visible inside router.php (and any requires in router.php), but it is visible in init.php.

What should I do to make it work?? I heard I should make things from config.php as global, but where should I put it to make it visible to router.php and any files required by it (and required by those files too).?

Thanks for answers guys :)

Comment: Look like a permission problem? CHMOD?

Comment: `I heard I should make things from config.php as global` Where did you hear that?

Comment: Try use `(var_dump(include('example.php')));` And if you receive false than this file can't re-require or is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require `config.php` and it looks like this:

```
<?php
$config = array();
$config['someOption'] = 'someValue';
```

$config should be available anywhere else in your code. However, if you are trying to access `$config` from a function, you must use the global keyword.

```
<?php
function someFunction()
{
    global $config;

    echo $config['someOption'];
}
```

My guess is you are missing the `global $config;` part in your code.

Comment: As an alternative to global variables, which can be annoying (some would say evil but I wouldn't go that far), you could have a static Config class with a `get()` method to retrieve values, and have the Config class get its values from an INI file using `parse_ini_file()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: Or the Config class's constructor could accept an array of options, e.g. `class Config {  static $options;  function __construct($options) { self::$options = $options; } ... }`

Comment: Yeah, I strongly recommend against global variables but if OP is using this approach, better approaches may be a little too complicated.

Comment: Good point...well if you're going to use globals, another alternative which I personally prefer is to use the `$GLOBALS` array...then just use `$GLOBALS['config']`.

Comment: thanks Matt B. - Your approach seems to be the best one (with static class and ini file parsing :) that will do for me mate!

Comment: Please Please Please avoid global variables. Not a good idea. Get name conflicts. Keep globals to a minimum.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to use a static class Ed :)